# How can you differentiate kick from kick at?

Tags: meaning

In English we can find both expressions: He kicked the door. and He kicked at the door. It seems to me that they have the same meaning. Can we find the context in which only one of them is appropriate but not the other.

Comment: No need to close this one, it has to do with linguistic aspect.

Comment: Agreed, way to stifle conversation about umm... Linguistics.

Comment: The way it's framed is a usage question. If it was how or why, then it would be on topic.